# How to set expandedTitleMarginBottom for CollapsingToolbarLayout programmatically

Tags: android, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout

We have some hidden views inside `CollapsingToolbarLayout`. So when we are making those view visible alignment of title is changed. so we need to change the value of `expandedTitleMarginBottom` for adjusting alignment.

How can we set `expandedTitleMarginBottom` for `CollapsingToolbarLayout` programmatically ?

Answer (score 0):

For anyone searching for this : you can call `setExpandedTitleMarginBottom(int px)` on the collapsibleToolbarLayout